# TypeError: string indices must be integers.What should I do to avoid this error

Tags: python-3.x

This is my dictionary `sd = gmaps.geocode('New Delhi')`

```
[{'address_components': [{'long_name': 'New Delhi', 'short_name': 'New Delhi', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Delhi', 'short_name': 'DL', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'India', 'short_name': 'IN', 'types': ['country', 'political']}], 'formatted_address': 'New Delhi, Delhi, India', 'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 28.65048, 'lng': 77.3449601}, 'southwest': {'lat': 28.4041, 'lng': 77.07301009999999}}, 'location': {'lat': 28.6139391, 'lng': 77.2090212}, 'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 28.65048, 'lng': 77.3449601}, 'southwest': {'lat': 28.4041, 'lng': 77.07301009999999}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJLbZ-NFv9DDkRzk0gTkm3wlI', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}]
```

I want to get a the int in `'lat'` and `'lng'` in `sd`

this is my line of codes

```
lat = []
lng = []
for x in sd:
    for y in sd:
        for z in y["geometry"]:
            lat.append(z["location"]["lat"])

for x in sd:
    for y in sd:
        for z in y["geometry"]:
            lng.append(z["location"]["lng"])

print(lat, lng)
```

When I run it this error will appear

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As y["geometry"] is dictionary not a list so we need to access in different way

Try Below code:

```
lat = []
lng = []
for x in sd:
    for y in sd:
        lat.append(y["geometry"]['location']['lat'])
        lng.append(y["geometry"]['location']['lng'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because rather then searching through dict, you are reading the key (or value)